# Convergence of $S_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i(i+1)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Is the series $S_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i(i+1)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j(j+1)}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}$ convergent?

We can already see that the left part $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i(i+1)}$ as well as the right part $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j(j+1)}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}$ are unbounded.

So we can't rule out that the series $S_n$ is convergent. However, I don't see how to manipulate the expression in a way that helps. Maybe someone else sees a clever transformation of $S_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=$$

$$\frac {n}{n+1}\sum _{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k} \le \sum _{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k}$$

on the other hand,$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j(j+1)}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}=$$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Thus $$S_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i(i+1)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j(j+1)}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}\le$$

$$\sum _{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}\le$$

$$\frac {1}{n}+\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {2k+1}{k(k+1)^2}$$
Which is convergent.

Comment: Why is it $\cdots\leq  \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {2k+1}{k(k+1)^2}$ and not $= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac {2k+1}{k(k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{n}$ in your last part?

Comment: I have edited the last part. Thanks, Philipp.

Comment: To dot i's... so $S_n$ is bounded  - as the sequence is also (positive) increasing, it converges.

Comment: Is there any chance of getting the limit of this series?